# Android uses-permission issue when installing apps in wrong order

Tags: android, permissions

I'm developing a couple of applications, one of them is acting as a "server" (let's call it Core) and the rest as clients. The Core app is a service running in background and the client apps use Core's provider to get data.

To do so, I've added [permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)s to my service app:

```
<permission android:name="com.mycompany.android.core.DATA_READ" />
<permission android:name="com.mycompany.android.core.DATA_WRITE" />
```

And my apps request the permissions:

```
    <!-- Permission to use Core's ContentProvider -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.mycompany.android.core.DATA_READ"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.mycompany.android.core.DATA_WRITE"/>
```

If I install Core in a device and then any of the apps, it works well, recognizes the permission and then executes normally.

But apps can also check if this Core app is installed in the device and then download it from Google Play, problem is, when I install Core after applications my permission is not recognized:

```
   W/ActivityManager(  751): Permission Denial: opening provider com.mycompany.android.core.db.DataProvider from ProcessRecord{23ee9d17 19907:com.mycompany.android.vanilla.ta/u0a120} (pid=19907, uid=10120) requires com.mycompany.android.core.DATA_READ or com.mycompany.android.core.DATA_WRITE
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907): Process: com.mycompany.android.vanilla.ta, PID: 19907
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.mycompany.android.core.db.DataProvider from ProcessRecord{23ee9d17 19907:com.mycompany.android.vanilla.ta/u0a120} (pid=19907, uid=10120) requires com.mycompany.android.core.DATA_READ or com.mycompany.android.core.DATA_WRITE
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3265)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4589)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2439)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1442)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:462)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at com.mycompany.android.app.data.ZKDataQueryResolver.executeQuery(ZKDataQueryResolver.java:123)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at com.mycompany.android.app.data.ZKDataQueryResolver.executeQuery(ZKDataQueryResolver.java:204)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at com.mycompany.android.vanilla.ta.BackgroundService.attemptLogin(BackgroundService.java:161)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at com.mycompany.android.vanilla.ta.LoginActivity$4.load(LoginActivity.java:180)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at com.mycompany.android.vanilla.ta.background.LoaderAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoaderAsyncTask.java:20)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at com.mycompany.android.vanilla.ta.background.LoaderAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoaderAsyncTask.java:8)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    E/AndroidRuntime(19907):    ... 4 more
    W/ActivityManager(  751):   Force finishing activity com.mycompany.android.vanilla.ta/.LoginActivity
```

My question is, how to "regenerate" the permissions after Core is installed without reinstalling the application?

**EDIT:**
My provider declaration is this:

```
   <!-- Here goes the DataProvider definition -->
    <provider
        android:name="com.mycompany.android.core.db.DataProvider"
        android:authorities="com.mycompany.android.core.db.DataProvider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:readPermission="com.mycompany.android.core.DATA_READ"
        android:writePermission="com.mycompany.android.core.DATA_WRITE" />
```

But I don't think the problem is here since it works well if Core application is installed before the rest of apps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is, how to "regenerate" the permissions after Core is installed without reinstalling the application?

Custom permissions are designed for firmware builders. While apps can create custom permissions, there are [security issues](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/02/12/vulnerabilities-custom-permissions.html) (mostly [pre-Android 5.0](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/08/04/custom-permission-vulnerability-l-developer-preview.html)), and the permissions must be defined before they can be held.

Your choices are:

- Require that Core be installed first, and that the other apps have to be reinstalled after Core is installed
- Define the custom permissions in all of your apps, using `<permission>` elements (though this will require all those apps be signed by the same signing key on Android 5.0+)

Comment: 'Define the custom permissions in all of your apps': Simple solution and just what I wanted, thank you! I didn't realized before.